# Merge two react projects with different Routers into one?

Tags: react-router

I am new to react. My usecase is like this :

I want to merge two react project(i.e. 1st and 2nd) one having `hashrouter` and the other having `browserrouter` .

What i had did ?

I tried to convert 1st App.js into a component(i.e.App1.js) and kept it in Routes.js file of 2nd project with path like this `<Route exact path='/App1' component={App1}/>` . It seems it is routing the page but the functionality of the 1st App.js file is not working.

I know what i explained top wouldn't be little difficult to understand . Apologizes for that.

What i want to know ?

Is it possible to keep different routers in the one project or Do i need to have only one router in the a project ?

Any help is appreciated ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you cannot have more than one router library. The functionality of `App1` is not working maybe because it use different configurations than the other project. Can you show us why `App1` is not working (any error message, warning will be appreciated)?

Comment: Thanks @jorj I didn't get any error msg. Basically , when i click on the icon it will route to a different page but it not routing .